# Strange exception on App Engine backend: "FrontendsNotSupported"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I'm getting FrontEndsNotSupported exception from a cron job's task handler, running on a backend. How to fix this?

The cron job is targeting the backend. The exception is triggered by start_new_background_thread, and is logged in the backend's log.

I have first seen this error a few days ago, roughly after my app was migrated to a newer app engine version.

Comment: Haven't seen this for a long while, must have been a temporary glitch.